# How to update/change webapp without stopping/restarting JAX-RS

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have developed RESTful Web Service, having webapp in it, using DropWizard.
I am facing a problem while running the service that I have to stop web service first, if I want to bring some changes in webapp (say HTML file).
I am using Eclipse IDE (though running service through CLI makes no difference).

Please guide me how can I bring changes in webapp without stopping web service and avoid cumbersome activity.

Comment: Looks like [DropWizard](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html) uses Jetty as the web container. Try searching for ways to have Jetty auto reload context. This thread may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767464/how-to-configure-jetty-to-reload-a-webappcontext-when-classes-are-changed

Comment: try [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/)